# String concatenation including variables in TCL

Tags: string, tcl

I am trying to accomplish something very simple in TCL. Namely string concatenation where some (not all) of the strings are assigned to variables. For example

```
set string1 fragilistic
set string2 docious

puts [concat supercali $string1 expiali $string 2]
```

this results in `supercali fragilistic expiali docious`. I really dont want those spaces in between so what I tried to do was

```
puts [concat supercali$string1expiali$string 2]
```

But this will return an error. How can I concatenate strings with strings assigned to variables in TCL without those intermediate spaces?

Answer (score 3):

You've got two options. The classic Tcl way of doing things is this, with brace-delimited variable names:

```
puts supercali${string1}expiali${string2}
```

From Tcl 8.6 onwards, there's also the command `string cat` (which was introduced to make `lmap` work better):

```
puts [string cat supercali $string1 expiali $string2]
```

Low-level behaviour should be identical.